# Skype command line arguments/URI for call initiation

Tags: command-line-arguments, skype

(I'm working on .NET but this is a general question which IMO would be similar in additional coding frameworks)

So I've been attempting to integrate a programmaticaly initiated video call via Skype.

SkypeSDK seems to have been discontinued a few years back, so I tried the URI system which the Skype team pushed instead of the SDK- using the Process start and passing URI as arguments- 
"Process.Start(tSkypeExePath, "skype:Echo123?call&video=true")"
...Doesn't work (focus is shifted to Skype but no call occurs)
Is URI restricted to web use (JS/ HTML) or I'm just not implementing it well?

Part2-
I tried running Skype with /callto arguments-
"Skype /callto:Echo123"
and this works, but couldn't find any info on automatically loading video with this method- as in video calling from the get-go. Is there a way to do this with arguments?

Part3- any idea why at times launching the process uses the existing Skype instance but more often that not a new instance is launched?

Thanks for your time,
Shaun

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no Skype support for using URIs in desktop applications. URIs would only
   work from web or an adaptation for iOS/Android (see skype's
   homepage)
2. Command line arguments would allow one to initiate a
   simple call to a recepient (optionally launching skype in the process) but not much more.
3. Skype has inner preferences for accepting (video) call automatically
4. One could "abuse" the focus command of skype (in preferences> advanced> shortcuts) paired with a keyboard simulated string (using SendKeys) to search for a user and initiate a (video) call to him, while keeping one's application on top to hide the skype interface. A bit ugly, but works